# Login system in symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-2.3, php-5.4

I tried to create an authentification system in symfony2 but no results. In the debug status bar for all situations I have : Logged as anon.

If I make a dump of session in the view I get :

```
"_security.last_error" => BadCredentialsException
```

My routing file:

```
shop_show_login_page:
  path: /login
  defaults: { _controller: ShopDesktopBundle:User:loginPage }

shop_login_user:
  path: /loginUser
  defaults: { _controller: ShopDesktopBundle:User:loginCheck }

shop_logout_user:
  path: /logout
```

My controller :

```
class UserController extends Controller{
public function loginPageAction(){
    return $this->render('ShopDesktopBundle:User:loginPage.html.twig');
}
public function loginCheckAction(){
    $request  = $this->getRequest();
    $password = $request->request->get('_password');
    $login    = $request->request->get('_username');
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $repository = $em->getRepository('ShopDesktopBundle:Customer');
    $user = $repository->findOneBy(array('customer_login'=> $login, 'customer_password'=> $password));
    if($user){
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('shop_desktop_homepage'));
    }else{
        return $this->render('ShopDesktopBundle:User:loginPage.html.twig',array('message_failed' => 'Eroare : login sau password este gresit'));
    }
}
}
```

My view :

```
<form action="{{ path('shop_login_user') }}" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="_username">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="_password">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="button">Autentificare</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Security.yml :

```
security:
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#encoding-the-user-s-password
encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#hierarchical-roles
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                user:  { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
                admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }

# the main part of the security, where you can set up firewalls
# for specific sections of your app
firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        form_login:
            check_path: shop_login_user
            login_path: shop_show_login_page
            username_parameter: _username
            password_parameter: _password
        logout:
            invalidate_session: true
            path:   shop_logout_user
            target: /
        anonymous: true
        #http_basic:
        #    realm: "Secured Demo Area"

# with these settings you can restrict or allow access for different parts
# of your application based on roles, ip, host or methods
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/access_control.html
access_control:
    #- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
```

I spent several days but no results. Help me please!!! Thx in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is, that you haven't updated your `user providers` In **security.yml** you still have a static list of users provided by the `in_memory` user provider. The security system is not aware of your own class `ShopDesktopBundle:Customer`.

If you follow the cookbook on "[How to Create a custom User Provider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html)", you should be able to solve it by:

**Update your User class**

Your user class `Customer` must implement [`UserInterface`](http://api.symfony.com/2.6/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserInterface.html) (and also recommended [`EquatableInterface`](http://api.symfony.com/2.6/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/EquatableInterface.html))

```
class Customer implements UserInterface, EquatableInterface { […] }
```

**Add a UserProvider**

You have to create a [`UserProvider`](http://api.symfony.com/2.6/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserProviderInterface.html), like:

```
class CustomerUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface {
    public function loadUserByUsername($username) { […]}
    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user) { […] }
    public function supportsClass($class) {
        return $class === 'Shop\DesktopBundle\Customer';
    }
}
```

**Create a service and update `user_provider` in *security.yml***

Finally create a service in your *service.yml* like:

```
services:
    customer_user_provider:
        class: Shop\DesktopBundle\CustomerUserProvider
```

And update *security.yml* like:

```
security:
    providers:
        webservice:
            id: customer_user_provider
```

Comment: @Gigel Try to follow "[How to Create a custom User Provider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html)" and adopt it to your setup, like I did in my answer. If this gets to complicated and as it seems that yo try to build a shop, where security matters, you could think about using a fully functional and maintained bundle like [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle).